# How to display plugin at the bottom of the add/edit post in admin area?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one plugin which i want to display at the bottom of the add/edit post in the admin section.

I have used action as,

add_action('edit_page_form','my_function');

but this displays the plugin in add/edit page also.which is not required for my plugin.
I only want to display the plugin box on the post page in admin area.

I have found

add_action('edit_category_form','my_function')

add_action('edit_tag_form','my_function')

add_action('dbx_post_advanced ','my_function')

but i have not found any action for post page to display the plugin only on the post page.
Any help for this?

Comment: You can try `edit_form_advanced` instead of `edit_page_form`

Comment: its working perfectly using edit_form_advanced.

Comment: its also working with edit_post_form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to add_action option for only post are :

1.`edit_form_advance` - my answer

2.`edit_post_form` - found by you :)

Regards